# Windows 10 keeps loading thumbnails like if cache doesn't work

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, cache

Windows 10 keeps loading thumbnails like if cache doesn't work

Here is quick e.g. video:
https://streamable.com/7n78n

I tried many things. Unchecked in explorer folder settings to never show thumbnails, only icons. Tried also deleting all the cache files, even all the .db files in folder `Explorer`. Disabled turning off caching thumbnails in gpedit.msc. Disabled turning off caching thumbnails in registry...

I don't even remember them all. But It's like it doesn't cache at all.

Tried to look to go `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer` them look on many many new images and see if the size of Explorer folder changes. And it is the same.

I don't know what is happening. To me it's like it always loads up thumbnails, doesn't take it from cache, maybe doesn't cache at all (seems to me like that). Maybe it's refreshing it all the time. Maybe reloading...

How to fix it?

---

CHKDSK: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dj2z.jpg

SFC: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBu1z.jpg

---

Using THUMBCACHE VIEWER:
[image]

Idk but really it's like there is no cache of those files or caching is disabled or broken somehow, but... idk

I look on images and size of thumbnails cache files doesn't go up.

My Explorer folder looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhHTU.jpg

---

Now I realized that some images cache properly... and some don't cache or cache not properly... I think. Cuz:
[image]
But even... why? What it depends on? hmmm

Comment: Try to rebuild the thumbnails cache. The simplest way is in Explorer to right-click `C:`, select Properties, click Disk Cleanup, tick Thumbnails and uncheck all the other options, click OK and then Delete Files.

Comment: Tried, didn't work. Tried also manualy delete all .db files by cmd @harrymc

Comment: Try doing `chkdsk` and [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc Done, but nothing changes. Result of those two added in question (edited)

Comment: We have established that your setup is healthy. I added an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all the places I know where thumbnails may be disabled:

- *Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Advanced* tab,
  under Performance click *Settings*, and ensure that *Show thumbnails instead of icons* is checked.
- In Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`), drill down to
  *User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > File Explorer*,
  and insure that this policy is Disabled or Not configured:
  *Turn off the caching of thumbnails in hidden thumbs.db files*.
- From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1248054/8672),
  ensure that the values `NoThumbnailCache` and `DisableThumbnailCache`
  do not exist for the following keys (delete if they exist):

  ```
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer]
  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
  ```

  Create perhaps a system restore point before hacking the registry.

Comment: Wowowowowowwowowowow.
Dude I was sitting with this problem for hours. Finally made it. I think some location of yours fixed the problem

Comment: I don't know exactly which, but the fix was one of the keys in windows's registry :). Thank you so much, love bro

Comment: Some of them I knew before. But you posted one that I didn't know and couldn't find anywhere on the web